# Preventing Focus event on Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page with a bunch of div elements in it. This page runs on a TV which is connected to a very slow settop box. The box runs the embbeded Opera browser version 9.50. The only input device I have is the STB's Remote Control, No mouse! In this web page (on TV) the user navigates around using the arrow up/down/left/right keys on the remote to go from one div to another since there's no mouse. Now, I'm trying to "debounce" theses keypresses when someone is pressing them too quickly! I can control the keypress events but I'm not having any luck with preventing the focus events, it seems like they're fired regardless what I do in the keypress handler anyway.

The question is: how can I prevent focus from going to another element inside the keypress handler of the current element? Calling keypress event.preventDefault() and returning false (from the keypress handler) does not prevent the focus from shifting to the next element. In other words the event "bubbles up" anyway. How can I prevent that?
I've played around with changing the tabIndex property too but it's no use.

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` within the handler?

Comment: What are the keypress events doing? Maybe they can go along with what the browser is trying to do by calling `.focus()` on the element instead?

Comment: You keep editing your question... Did you try my answer? Use `keydown` instead. Also the problem is not related to event bubbling, bubbling only refers to handlers on parent nodes, `preventDefault` doesn't stop bubbling, it just prevent the browser from taking the default action. Just wanted to make sure your terminology is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent focus from a click event, you have to `e.preventDefault()` from the `mousedown` handler. Can't do it from the `click` handler since that is not a physical event, it's just an abstraction of `mousedown` and `mouseup`

If you want to prevent tab from changing focus, you have to `e.preventDefault()` from the keydown handler. Can't do it from `keypress`, because `keypress` is not a physical event, it's an abstraction of `keydown` and `keyup` events (notice that keypress fires multiple times when you hold down the key).

http://jsfiddle.net/gtwhF/

```
$('#a').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})

$('#a').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9) { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
  } 
})
```

Comment: Thank Juan but it is not working in Opera. See the log snippet: 04/16/2013 13:51:37.319 Info: RemoteControl: OnKeyDown: Debouncer prevented: keyCode = 65521 on divMoreCategoriesButton  
04/16/2013 13:51:37.335 Info: RemoteControl: OnKeyPress: keyCode = 65521 srcElementId = divMoreCategoriesButton

Comment: Notice even though the keyDown handler prevented keyCode 65521, the keyPress handler was still called!